# Find a real number $ \ x \ $ such that $ \ \left[ \frac{\large [x]}{2}\right] \neq \left[ \frac{x}{2}\right] $

Tags: functions

Find a real number $x$ such that $\left[ \frac{\large [x]}{2}\right] \neq \left[ \frac{x}{2}\right] $ and a real number $y$ such that $\left[ \frac{\large [y]}{2}\right] \neq \left[ \frac{y}{2}\right] $, where $ \ [z] \ $ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $z$.

**Answer:**

I see that for all real numbers $x$, we have

$$ \left[ \frac{\large [x]}{2}\right]=\left[ \frac{x}{2}\right] \ $$ holds.

So how to answer the question?

Comment: Both your question about $x$ and the question about $y$ are identical.  Did you perhaps mean to have one using the floor function and the other using the ceiling function in some manner?

Comment: For questions phrased like this, an answer of "*It can't be done [because...]*" is perfectly valid and acceptable.

Comment: If indeed you have found that to be so, then there is no such number and the answer is "It can't be done".  But you do have to verify that $[\frac {[x]}2] = [\frac {x}2]$ is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1:  $[x]= 2k + 1$ is odd.  Then $2k + 1 \le x < 2k + 2$ and and $k < k + \frac 12 \le \frac x2 < k + 1$ so $[\frac x2] = k$.  And $\frac {[x]}2 = k +\frac 12$ and so $[\frac {[x]}2] = k = [\frac x2]$.

Case 2: $[x] = 2k$ is even.  Then $2k \le x < 2k + 1$ and $k \le \frac x2 < k +\frac 12< k+1$ so $[\frac x2] = k$.  And $\frac {[x]}2 = k$ and so $[\frac {[x]}2] = k = [\frac x2]$.

So such a number does not exist.